# AIX ( UNIX ) / Linux Shell. Why cant I call a variable that I exported

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, scripting, export

Will be v terse w/ my Q here  
 . Take a look at this ( made it as 'generic' as poss - adhering to not discuss a specific code  review much as a can be - stack guideline )

```
# some 'echos' &  'exports'  might sound redundant agreed. That was to make sure I did not miss out on anything 
g=rf1.`date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M'`.log ;export pat x ; 
for d in  `find <path> -type d -maxdepth 1`  ; 
do r=`basename "$d"` ;echo "\$r basename is $r"; 
# there can be multiple matches . pat is an array that can capture this 
 ( [[  -n `ls  /<path>/*file*.ext 2>/dev/null` ]] 
&& 
 ( pat=( $(ls  /<path>/*file*.ext ) ) ; 
# confirming that val is captured  by x  
# I am grabbing the value of pat for testing 
echo "\$pat is $pat"; export pat ; export 
x=${pat[0]}; 
echo "x is $x " ;  ) )  
|| ( echo "did not find ya da ya "   ) ; 
echo "Repeat -\$x is $x"  ;  
< some more  code that tests the value of x and 
proceeds > ; 
done |  tee /<path>  2>&1
```

I grabbed the value of `array pat` into `var x`  but  not withstanding all my tweaks I could not get it to out put the value captured  in the latter part where I wanted to use it. aka `echo "\$pat is $pat"; export pat ; export x=${pat[0]}; echo "$\x is $x` will give values but  at `echo "Repeat -\$x is $x"`  it gives nothing. Why so 
 BTW I have found several workarounds. So I am not looking for code fixes but wanna know *why*  `$x` gets  forgotten in the 2nd part .  
 PS This is a quickie I ran on the command line. for the small time didnt feel like putting it in a script

Comment: Most likely your variable assignement was in a subshell, so it got lost when the subshell exited. `A=1; (A=2; echo $A); echo $A`

Comment: right but doesn't exporting so that very purpose to not let the variable get lost

Comment: Environment variables are never passed from child to parent, only from parent to child.